# Open-source animation library compatible with simpy

Tags: python, simpy

Is it possible to combine `simpy` discrete-event simulation library with any open-source animation tool in order to simply visualize a queue system? I know it's possible to use `matplotlib`, but it rather serves for creating charts, not for building animations, e.g. the arrivals and departures of entities, and their servicing (showing that the resource is busy or idle).

For instance, I found `panda3d` which is the game and simulation engine, but in case of using this tool I would need to probably program all the movement trajectories of entities, and it looks like overcomplication of what I really need.

Comment: Just try it out and share your results with the SimPy mailing list.